# dat.gui display simple text

Tags: text, dat.gui

Is it possible to display a simple text in dat.gui?

A text input field can be achieved, but I would like to use dat.gui to display comments, such as the application controls. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is.

First you will have to determine the location of your particular text. It will be either in `gui.__controllers` or `gui.__folders.__controllers`.

For instance, I have a Folder called "Animation", and inside this folder I have a simple text display. But to get rid of input that is associated with the simple text display, you have to manipulate the `domElement`.

The command below,

`gui.__folders["Animation"].__controllers[0].domElement.hidden = true`;

will hide the 'input' and only display the 'application controls'.